# Can't change brightness: Fujitsu Amilo li3710 & Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, brightness, fujitsu-siemens

I can't change the screen brightness on my Fujitsu Amilo li3710. Pressing the keys (Fn+Brightness up) or sliding the bar in Brightness&Lock has no effect. It worked on windows so the function is supported by the hardware. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same setup.  I just tried, and it works.  Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I tried but still not working :(. Could you provide more details regarding your system? Are you using 32 or 64 bits version?

Comment: Have you tried adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to /etc/default/grub? If not open the terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and where it says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"` change it to say `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`. Now save this file, and then in the terminal type `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes you just made. Reboot and then test the brightness controls!

Comment: That's amazing, thanks! there was GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"; I made them both "quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor". I can now dim the brightness from Brightness&Lock. The Fn key binding is not working though, any ideas on how I might get that working? Thanks.